# How to find (grand)children in XML according to attribute only in python?

Tags: python, xml, xpath

An file.xml example.

```
<root>
    <child1 attrib='attrib1'>
    </child1>

    <child2 attrib='attrib1'>
    </child2>

    <child3 attrib='attrib2'>
    </child3>

    <child3 attrib='attrib3'>
    </child3>
</root>
```

I prefer to use elementtree to parse. The root node is obtained as

```
tree=xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

To get to the first `child3`, I can use

```
root.findall(".//child3[@attrib='attrib2'])
```

But this is based on assumption of I knowing tag name of `child3`.

I have the following two issues:

1. If I don't pre-know tag names of `child1` and `child2`, how can I get to these two children? A way of one line command `root.findall(".//[@attrib='attrib1'])` seems not working.
2. Is there a way of using a variable to replace the exact attribute name? For example, if I define `attribVar='attrib'`, but `[@attribVar='attrib1']` is not working.

Comment: You can use `.//*[@attrib='attrib1']` to select *any* element which has an `attrib` attribute equal to `attrib1`. Please edit your question and format your XML code correctly. The attributes are not shown as attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
.//*[@attrib='attrib1']
```

to select *any* element which has an `attrib` attribute *equal* to `attrib1`.

You can use

```
.//*[contains(@attrib,'attrib')]
```

to select any element which has an `attrib` attribute that *contains* the string `'attrib'`. This will match `attrib1` and `attrib2` (but will also match `mattrib` and `attribute`).

You can pass the name of the attributes in Python using string interpolation:

```
attributes = ['attrib1', 'attrib2', 'attrib3'];
for attr in attributes:
    print root.findall(".//*[@attrib='{0}']".format(attr));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution of the first issue. 

For the second issue, to make it more clear, denote one of attributes having name attName and value attVal, i.e., attName='attVal'. There is no problem of format .//*[@attName='attVal']. My question is I want to use another variable to replace attName. For example, if I define attVar='attName', how do I use attVar in above format? (withou any appearance of attName)

Comment: You can do that in Python. I added an example.